# I'm using a project that capture screenshots from games but breakpoints never work why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I downloaded the project the zip file from here:

[ScreenShots](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook)

And loaded the project to visual studio and i see two projects.
The first one is the library code i can't run it i get error message that i need to use another project and runb it from there. So there is another project already the owner a test project but when i add breakpoints to the first project it never stop there.

[image: The two projects and a breakpoint]

what i wanted to do is to lock on the frames per seconds that the first project draw on the game screen for example in one of the games i see the fps move between 60-61fps average so i wanted to take screenshots at the fps that the program show/draw on the game window.

In form1 i did:

```
pictureBox1.Image = screenshot.CapturedBitmap.ToBitmap();
count++;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(screenshot.CapturedBitmap.ToBitmap());
bmp.Save(@"C:\Temp\Screenshots\" + count.ToString("D6") + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I did that each time i click the button to capture a screenshot Request Capture button it will save to the hard disk a image jpeg.

Now instead using the button i wanted to use my oqn timer but that won't be good enough i think so i wanted to lock on the fps that the program show.
So i tried to use breakpoints on every places in the project that using the fps but it never stop there.

I guess that the TestScreenshot project is not connected with the Capture project.
So when i add breakpoints on the Capture project but run the TestScreenshot project it's never stop on the Capture project.

How can i use breakpoints on the Capture project ?
And how can i lock on the Capture project fps so if it's showing 60fps then save on my hard disk 60 images per second ?

Comment: Please post actual code and not screenshots.

Comment: I can't upload here all the code it's very long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the breakpoints you need to add them at the statement when the test project call the library, for the fps you should use this mathemtical statement for each fps rate on your timer interval :

```
miliseconds = 1000 / fps
```

For further infos please comment.